# Joining table to two other tables in single query

Tags: mysql, join

I am getting rows from `table_a` by joining it to `table_b` in this way:

```
select ta.* from table_a as ta 
inner join table_b as tb on ta.first_column=tb.first_column 
where tb.second_column='myvalue';
```

And,

I am getting rows from `table_a` by joining it to `table_c` in this way:

```
select ta.* from table_a as ta 
inner join table_c as tc on ta.first_column=tc.first_column 
where tc.second_column='myvalue';
```

How can I form a single query to get all the rows of the above queries (i.e. union of the results from the above queries)?

I do not want to do an Union per se, but rather do it by forming a query which joins `table_a` to `table_b` and `table_c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do multiple joins in the same query.

```
select ta.*,tb.*,tc.* from table_a as ta 
inner join table_b as tb on ta.first_column=tb.first_column 
inner join table_c as tc on ta.first_column=tc.first_column 
where tc.second_column='myvalue' and tb.second_column='myvalue';
```

If you want all the records for which the second_column is 'myvalue' for both tables(b and c) at the same time you will use the query above with the `and` conjunction in the where clause.

Otherwise, if you wantall the records for which the second_column is 'myvalue' for at least 1 of he tables(b or c) you will replace the `and` cojunction with  `or`.

---

**Update**
If you don't want just the rows for which first_column was common in table_b and table_c as you described try this:

```
select distinct ta.* from table_a as ta 
left join table_b as tb on ta.first_column=tb.first_column 
left join table_c as tc on ta.first_column=tc.first_column 
where tc.second_column='myvalue' or tb.second_column='myvalue';
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It considers rows only where `tb.first_column = tc.first_column` (Even if I completely removed `where` filter, just kept two joins, and I still got only those rows for which `first_column` was common in table_b and table_c)